# python osmnx geocode_to_gdf Nominatim not working while web-based openstreetmaps does

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geocoding, nominatim

I am trying to geocode a list of objects (mostly road names) to their coordinates from python wth `osmnx.geocode_to_gdf`.
The problem is that I often  get returned with the following error message (example of query *"Jln Kuang, Singapore"*):

```
ValueError: Nominatim could not geocode query "Jln Kuang, Singapore" to polygonal boundaries
```

While using the same exact query in the web version of Open Street Map  I do get the correct result, in this case pointing me to the right road.

[image]